# $.Ajax throwing "Invalid argument" on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, internet-explorer

I have the following code setup:

```
var formData = new FormData();
var url = config.getValue("api.baseLocation") + config.getValue("api.upload");
formData.append("scopeInfo", JSON.stringify($scope.video));
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
        alert("error " + XMLHttpRequest + ' - ' + textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    toast("Completed!", 4000);
    window.history.back();
});
```

And this works great on FF, Chrome. For IE9 I had to add a fix to support the FormData ([FormDatafix](https://github.com/francois2metz/html5-formdata))

When I click submit, on IE9 it gives me `Error: Invalid argument.`

I have no clue why this is happening, nor on what argument it's referring to.
I tried setting the following attributes, but non of them made a difference:

- `cache: false`
- `dataType: "json"`
- `crossDomain: true`

Comment: Do a `console.log` on the parameters you're passing in, i.e. `url` and `formData` - make sure they're what you expect. Been a while since I did IE debugging, you might need another JS script included to see console output.

Comment: I may be wrong, but `contentType` must be string, and can't be false

Comment: what line is giving you the error?

Comment: @Justinas It can be boolean: `As of jQuery 1.6 you can pass false to tell jQuery to not set any content type header.`

Comment: @Bulk removing console.log changes it to: 'no transport', then adding `crossDomain: true` again it went back to 'Error: Invalid argument.` And it's logging the thingies, but nothing usefull / wrong with param

Comment: What does this function do: `toast("Completed!", 4000);`

Comment: Not sure, but just a guess. Try and replace `XMLHttpRequest` with `qXHR` as IE may not like a reserved function to be used as a function argument!

Comment: @ArinCool, it makes a Toast :D naah just kidding, it's something from materializecss. For giving the user some feedback

Comment: @LShetty same deal :)

Comment: Unless you post your whole JS code and HTML or post a fiddle (replicating the issue), I think it will not be possible for anyone to identify

Answer (score 0):

I changed the way I handle the post in the API, IE9 was perfectly able to send Json data, so in the API I processed things to support that. and now it's working like it should